# FramenetError: Unknown frame

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I run:

```
from nltk.corpus import framenet as fn
fn.frames()
```

And get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/framenet.py", line 1308, in frame_by_name
    elt = XMLCorpusView(locpath, 'frame')[0]
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/xmldocs.py", line 155, in __init__
    encoding = self._detect_encoding(fileid)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/xmldocs.py", line 166, in _detect_encoding
    with open(fileid, 'rb') as infile:
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/me/nltk_data/corpora/framenet_v17.zip/framenet_v17/frame/Abandonment.xml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/framenet.py", line 876, in __repr__
    for elt in self:
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/collections.py", line 406, in iterate_from
    try: yield self._func(self._lists[0][index])
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/framenet.py", line 1407, in frame
    f = self.frame_by_id(fn_fid_or_fname, ignorekeys)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/framenet.py", line 1268, in frame_by_id
    return self.frame_by_name(name, ignorekeys, check_cache=False)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/framenet.py", line 1310, in frame_by_name
    raise FramenetError('Unknown frame: {0}'.format(fn_fname))
nltk.corpus.reader.framenet.FramenetError: Unknown frame: Abandonment
```

Both the Framenet 1.5 and 1.7 corpora are installed, according to nltk.download()

Comment: if you run `nltk.__version__` which version does it return? I ran your code in version `3.3` and didn't get an error.

Comment: Odd. I just checked: nltk.__version__
'3.3'

Comment: Aaaand it's working. I have no idea what I did to change anything. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe it was the prayers! Haha